# Handle timezone inferior to unix epoch time

Tags: hive, timestamp

I want to md5 a timestamp column in Hive, without the millisecond.
If timestamp is before Epoch Unix Time (year 1970), timestamp is corrupted:
START_DATE=1915-07-15 23:25:26.290448384

```
select ID, START_DATE, MD5(START_DATE) from TABLE1
```

Result : START_DATE = 2500-02-02 00:00:00.0

No issue without adding MD5 function, or if the timestamp > 1970.

I've tried with vectorized parameter (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/hive/vectorized+query+execution#VectorizedQueryExecution-Limitations) but still the same issue.
Also tried : Cast as string, substr... before MD5.

How can we handle timestamp < 1970 ?

Comment: Problem solved. The real value of START_DATE was 2500... (checked in the ORC file). Changing to false 2 parameters (hive.vectorized.execution.reduce.enabled and hive.vectorized.execution.enabled) solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you use somethign like this ?

```
select md5(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(substring('1915-07-15 23:25:26.290448384',1,19)))) as md5_out
```

[image: output]

Unixtime will calculate any date before 1970 as negative number and calculate accordingly. so i think it should be alright.

Comment: Thanks, it's working if your input is a string (like in your exemple). But as soon as it's a timestamp, it breaks the value. It seems that any operation on the timestamp before 1970 will fail...

Comment: Problem solved. The real value of START_DATE was 2500... (checked in the ORC file). Changing to false 2 parameters (hive.vectorized.execution.reduce.enabled and hive.vectorized.execution.enabled) solve the problem.